# MobileFirst8.0- Unable to delete Adapters and Applications form Application Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-console

I am unable to delete adapters/applications from the console, it is continuously showing:

> RuntimeException: Synchronization failure

Screenshot attached [image]

**Messages.log**

> [10/26/16 17:59:34:790 IST] 00000021 com.mfp.adapter.SecurityAdapterApplication                   I Adapter initialized!
>   [10/26/16 17:59:34:797 IST] **00000021 rnal.connectivity.synchronization.RuntimeSynchronizationBean E FWLSE0324: Runtime synchronization failed. Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No resource classes found for adapter 'SecurityAdapter'**
>   com.ibm.mfp.server.core.shared.deployment.DeploymentException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No resource classes found for adapter 'SecurityAdapter'
>       at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.internal.deploy.JaxRsSandboxDeploymentHandler.deploy(JaxRsSandboxDeploymentHandler.java:131)
>       at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.internal.deploy.JaxRsSandboxDeploymentHandler.deploy(JaxRsSandboxDeploymentHandler.java:47)
>       at com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
>       at com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:484)
>       at com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.DeploymentManagerImpl.changeDeploymentState(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:360)
>       at com.ibm.mfp.server.mgmt.internal.connectivity.synchronization.RuntimeSynchronizationBean.sync(RuntimeSynchronizationBean.java:207)
>       at com.ibm.mfp.server.mgmt.internal.connectivity.synchronization.RuntimeMBeanExporterListener.mbeanRegistered(RuntimeMBeanExporterListener.java:71)
>       at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.notifyListenersOfRegistration(MBeanExporter.java:1055)
>       at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.onRegister(MBeanExporter.java:1029)
>       at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.onRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:301)
>       at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:229)
>       at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:670)
>       at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:615)
>       at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:550)
>       at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:432)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:332)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1423)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:1180)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:1148)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1054)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6448)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:446)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApplication(DynamicVirtualHost.java:441)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startWebApplication(WebContainer.java:981)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startModule(WebContainer.java:805)
>       at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.web.internal.WebModuleHandlerImpl.deployModule(WebModuleHandlerImpl.java:102)
>       at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployModule(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:870)
>       at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployModules(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:830)
>       at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployApp(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:817)
>       at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.war.internal.WARApplicationHandlerImpl.install(WARApplicationHandlerImpl.java:66)
>       at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction.execute(StartAction.java:139)
>       at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.enterState(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:1168)
>       at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.run(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:781)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No resource classes found for adapter 'SecurityAdapter'
>       at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.shared.JAXRSSandbox.produceSwaggerDoc(JAXRSSandbox.java:241)
>       at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.shared.JAXRSSandbox.init(JAXRSSandbox.java:165)
>       at com.ibm.mfp.server.java.adapter.internal.deploy.JaxRsSandboxDeploymentHandler.deploy(JaxRsSandboxDeploymentHandler.java:119)
>       ... 45 more
>
> [10/26/16 17:59:34:802 IST] 00000021 connectivity.synchronization.AdminSynchronizationInterceptor I Runtime service is blocked, current state: synchronization required
>   [10/26/16 17:59:34:804 IST] 00000067 com.mfp.datamatics.IntegrationAdapterStubApplication         I Adapter destroyed!

Comment: Is this a devkit installation? If yes, please provide the log file, located at installation-folder/mfp-server/usr/servers/mfp/logs/messages.log.

Comment: Yes. It is devkit installation.

Comment: Messages.log added below

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear how you managed to get to this error:

> FWLSE0324: Runtime synchronization failed. Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No resource classes found for adapter 'SecurityAdapter'

On the surface, this error likely means that you deleted the resource .java file from your adapter, but kept the `JAXRSApplicationClass` definition of the resource in the **adapter.xml** file.

**To better understand the problem, please upload your .adapter file somewhere so it could be debugged.**

As for what you can do in the meanwhile to clear the database, I tried various ways but looks like only a re-install of the devkit currently works...

Comment: I have also reinstall devkit and it works but how to uninstall the old devkit? Is it just to delete the folder?

Comment: Yes, simply delete the folder.